# overriding function calls from SVML

Tags: c++, linker, icc, xeon-phi, avx512

The Xeon-Phi Knights Landing cores have a fast `exp2` instruction `vexp2pd` (intrinsic `_mm512_exp2a23_pd`). The Intel C++ compiler can vectorize the `exp` function using the Short Vector Math Library (SVML) which comes with the compiler.  Specifically, it calls the fuction `__svml_exp8`.

However, when I step through a debugger I don't see that `__svml_exp8` uses the `vexp2pd` instruction. It is a complication function with many FMA operations. I understand that `vexp2pd` is less accurate than `exp` but if I use `-fp-model fast=1` (the default) or `fp-model fast=2` I expect the compiler to use this instruction but it does not.

I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to get the compiler to use `vexp2pd`?
2. How do I safely override the call to `__svml_exp8`?

As to the second question this is what I have done so far.

```c
//exp(x) = exp2(log2(e)*x)  
extern "C" __m512d __svml_exp8(__m512d x) {        
    return _mm512_exp2a23_pd(_mm512_mul_pd(_mm512_set1_pd(M_LOG2E), x));
}
```

**Is this safe? Is there a better solution e.g. one that inlines the function?** In the test code below this is about 3 times faster than if I don't override.

```
//https://godbolt.org/g/adI11c
//icpc -O3 -xMIC-AVX512 foo.cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

extern "C" __m512d __svml_exp8(__m512d x) {
  //exp(x) = exp2(log2(e)*x)  
  return _mm512_exp2a23_pd(_mm512_mul_pd(_mm512_set1_pd(M_LOG2E), x));
}

void foo(double * __restrict x, double * __restrict y) {
  __assume_aligned(x, 64);
  __assume_aligned(y, 64);
  for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) y[i] = exp(x[i]);
}

int main(void) {
  double x[1024], y[1024];
  for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) x[i] = 1.0*i;
  for(int r=0; r<1000000; r++) foo(x,y);
  double sum=0;
  //for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) sum+=y[i];
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%f ", y[i]); puts("");
  //printf("%lf",sum);
}
```

Comment: You're asking the compiler to throw away 30 bits of precision by using `vexp2pd`. It's not going to do that even with fast-math.

Comment: @Mysticial I am pretty sure I noticed the compiler use `vrcp28pd` (actually you can see it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/Wya9Ic)). So if it's using a fast reciprocal why not a fast `exp`? Looking at that code with the reciprocal it looks like maybe it's doing one iteration of newton or something (otherwise what's up with all the FMAs). That may explain why it uses the fast reciprocal and not the fast `exp`.

Comment: I have never heard of `vfixupimmpd`. Strange instruction. Intrinsic guide says it requires AVXVL but the copmiler generates it for KNL which does not have AVXVL.

Comment: Correct, a single Newton iteration (2 FMAs) is enough to get a 28-bit reciprocal out to 53 (-1ulp precision loss). No such iteration exists for `exp`. `vfixupimmpd` isn't VL, it's F. Only the <512-bit versions are VL.

Comment: Thanks! Still it would be useful to have the compiler generate `vexp2pd`. Before I overrode the `svml` function I had to rewrite an entire region of code which vectorized trivially otherwise just to get `vexp2pd`. I only though of overriding `svml` yesterday and got it working today. It's the first time I have done something like this but it seems to work. Now I need to prove if 23bits is enough. OTOH it does not make much difference in the overall performance so it's probably no longer worth the trouble.

Comment: `vexp2pd` doesn't give you full precision. Only 23. So you can't get the compiler to auto-generate `vexp2pd`  (maybe if you cast down to `float` and back) OTOH, what if you're using `float`s the whole way, then the compiler will probably be smart enough to auto-vectorize to `vexp2ps`.

Comment: @Mysticial, you are totally right! Changing from double to float uses `vexp2ps` and no longer uses SVML.  I guess `vexp2pd` is really a single floating point instruction (KNC has something like) as the error is the same for both single and float.

Comment: @Mysticial, I added an answer and made it community wiki. Please feel free to edit it if you have anything you think is worth adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ICC will generate vexp2pd but only under very much relaxed math requirements as specified by targeted -fimf* switches.

```
#include <math.h>

void vfoo(int n, double * a, double * r)
{
    int i;
    #pragma simd
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        r[i] = exp(a[i]);
    }
}
```

E.g. compile with -xMIC-AVX512 -fimf-domain-exclusion=1 -fimf-accuracy-bits=22

```
..B1.12:
        vmovups   (%rsi,%rax,8), %zmm0
        vmulpd    .L_2il0floatpacket.2(%rip){1to8}, %zmm0, %zmm1
        vexp2pd   %zmm1, %zmm2
        vmovupd   %zmm2, (%rcx,%rax,8)
        addq      $8, %rax
        cmpq      %r8, %rax
        jb        ..B1.12
```

Please be sure to understand the accuracy implications as not only the end result is only about 22 bits accurate, but the vexp2pd also flushes to zero any denormalized results irrespective of the FTZ/DAZ bits set in the MXCSR.

To the second question: **"How do I safely override the call to __svml_exp8?"**
Your approach is generally not safe. SVML routines are internal to Intel Compiler and rely on custom calling conventions, so a generic routine with the same name can potentially clobber more registers than a library routine would, and you may end up in a hard-to-debug ABI mismatch.

A better way of providing your own vector functions would be to utilize #pragma omp declare simd, e.g. see https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524514 and possibly the vector_variant attribute if prefer coding with intrinsics, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523350. Just don't try to override standard math names or you'll get an error.

Comment: Your code does not produce `vexp2pd` for me with ICC 17. I have tried many variations. But if I replace `exp` with `exp2` in the code in your answer then it does produce `vexp2pd`.

Comment: Please try with 18.0 (currently in beta)